# Proof of sequential limit theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

There's just one line in the proof I don't understand.

> Because $(b_n) \rightarrow b$, there exists an $N$ such that $|b_n - b| < \frac{|b|}{2}$ for all $n>N$.  This implies $|b_n| > \frac{|b|}{2}$.

I understand the first sentence, but not the second.

Comment: Draw a picture on the XY-plane with a sequence $(b_n)$ of points converging to a horizontal line at $y=b$. Take $b>0$ for simplicity. Does that help?

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense now.  And in this case we specified b not equal to zero so I don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

As $|b|-|b_n| \le |b-b_n| < |b|/2$ (this is the triangle inequality), $|b_n| > |b|/2$.

Comment: It's actually |bn| > |b|/2, not |bn| < |b|/2.

Comment: http://imgur.com/8OyrqCi

Comment: But no worries I figured it out now